# Getting an error when I try to use ".remove()"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a BlackJack game in HTML/CSS/JS as practice.
I am trying to remove the card images I added, after "Play Again" is clicked, but I get an error.

I have tried moving the code to the start of the "startGame()" function, and that removed the images, but it also resulted in no images being printed (or them getting removed instantly i guess).

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```js
let cardValues = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "J", "Q", "K"];
let cardSuits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"];
let deck = new Array();
let players = new Array();
let dealerCard;
let hiddenCard;
let dealerTotal = 0;
let playerCard1;
let playerCard2;
let playerTotal = 0;

window.onload = function() {
    startGame()
}

function startGame() {  
    document.getElementById("game-over").style.visibility = "hidden";
    makeDeck();
    shuffleDeck(deck);
    runGame();
}
function makeDeck() {
    deck = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < cardValues.length; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < cardSuits.length; j++)
        {
            let weight = parseInt(cardValues[i]);
            if (cardValues[i] == "J" || cardValues[i] == "Q" || cardValues[i] == "K")
            {
                weight = 10;
            } else if (cardValues[i] == "A")
            {
                weight = 11;
            }
            let card = {cardValue: cardValues[i], cardSuit: cardSuits[j], cardWeight: weight}
            deck.push(card)
        }
    }
}

function shuffleDeck(deck) {
    for (let i = deck.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [deck[i], deck[j]] = [deck[j], deck[i]];
    }
}

function runGame() {
    hiddenCard = deck.pop();
    dealerTotal += hiddenCard.cardWeight;
    console.log(hiddenCard)

    while (dealerTotal < 17) {
        let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
        let card = deck.pop();
        cardImg.src = "/assets/img/" + card.cardValue + "_" + card.cardSuit + ".png";
        cardImg.classList.add("card-image")
        document.getElementById("dealer-cards").append(cardImg);
        dealerTotal += card.cardWeight;
        console.log(dealerTotal);  
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
        let card = deck.pop();
        cardImg.src = "/assets/img/" + card.cardValue + "_" + card.cardSuit + ".png";
        document.getElementById("player-cards").append(cardImg);
        playerTotal += card.cardWeight;
    }  
}

function hit() {
    let card = deck.pop();
    let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
    cardImg.src = "/assets/img/" + card.cardValue + "_" + card.cardSuit + ".png";
    document.getElementById("player-cards").append(cardImg);
    playerTotal += card.cardWeight;
    checkGameOver()
}

function playAgain() {
    playerTotal = 0;
    dealerTotal = 0; 
    let cardImg = $(document.getElementsByClassName("card-image"))
    $(cardImg).remove();
    startGame();
}

function checkGameOver() {
    if (playerTotal > 21) {
        console.log("Game Over");
        document.getElementById("game-over").style.visibility = "visible";
        return true;
    } else if (playerTotal <= 21) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
}

body {
    font-family:Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #006611;

}

h2 {
    padding: 20px;
}


.board-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dealer, .player {
    background: #0d7e20;
    height: 25%;
    width: auto;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5px
}

.dealer img, .player img {
    margin: 50px;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    height: 190px;
    width: 140px;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons button {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: #b30000;
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 39px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
    background-color: #e40000;
}

#game-over {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:  #00000070;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.game-over-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: rgb(0, 112, 37);
    height: 8vw;
    width: 18vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

#play-again {
    background-color: #b30000;
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blackjack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="board-container">
        <h2>Dealer: <span id="dealer-total"></h2>
        <div class="dealer" id="dealer-cards">
            <img id="hidden-card"src="/assets/img/cardBack_blue.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <h2>You: <span id="player-total"></h2>
        <div class="player" id="player-cards">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button onclick=hit() id="hitBtn">Hit</button>
            <button id="stayBtn">Stay</button>
        </div>       
    </div>
    <div id="game-over">
        <div class="game-over-container">
            <span>Game Over</span>
            <button id="play-again" onclick=playAgain()>Play Again</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Image of the error:]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You're using `$`, but you never loaded jQuery.

Comment: Why do you need to use `$`? Just use `let cardImg = document.getElementsByClassName("card-image"); cardImage.remove()`

Comment: @Barmar - That's what I started with, I added the $, after looking online to try and fix it. But the same thing happened during both instances. I've never used jQuery before, so I wasn't aware that was needed.

Comment: @James - the error im getting is: scripts.js:85 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at playAgain (scripts.js:85:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:29:57)

Comment: @Barmar - After removing the "$", I am getting a different error: Uncaught TypeError: cardImg.remove is not a function
    at playAgain (scripts.js:86:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:29:57)

Comment: @Barmar cardImg is going to be a collection of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, you can rewrite

```
let cardImg = $(document.getElementsByClassName("card-image"))
$(cardImg).remove();
```

as

```
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card-image");
for (let card of cards) card.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your fix gets rid of the error, but it still doesn't remove the images.

Comment: True, it won't remove the images, because none of the images have class="card-image".  You would need to add `cardImg.className='card-image';` to the places you create cardImg.

Comment: Only the dealer's card has the `card-image` class.

Comment: You're right about that! I completely forgot to add it to the player cards. But I tried your fixes and i'm sadly still getting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `$`, you need to load the jQuery library. But there's no need for it here, since vanilla DOM JS also has a `.remove()` method.

Since `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a `NodeList`, you have to loop over it to remove all of them.

You need to add the `card-image` class whenever you create a new card.

```js
let cardValues = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "J", "Q", "K"];
let cardSuits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"];
let deck = new Array();
let players = new Array();
let dealerCard;
let hiddenCard;
let dealerTotal = 0;
let playerCard1;
let playerCard2;
let playerTotal = 0;

window.onload = function() {
    startGame()
}

function startGame() {  
    document.getElementById("game-over").style.visibility = "hidden";
    makeDeck();
    shuffleDeck(deck);
    runGame();
}
function makeDeck() {
    deck = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < cardValues.length; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j < cardSuits.length; j++)
        {
            let weight = parseInt(cardValues[i]);
            if (cardValues[i] == "J" || cardValues[i] == "Q" || cardValues[i] == "K")
            {
                weight = 10;
            } else if (cardValues[i] == "A")
            {
                weight = 11;
            }
            let card = {cardValue: cardValues[i], cardSuit: cardSuits[j], cardWeight: weight}
            deck.push(card)
        }
    }
}

function shuffleDeck(deck) {
    for (let i = deck.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [deck[i], deck[j]] = [deck[j], deck[i]];
    }
}

function runGame() {
    hiddenCard = deck.pop();
    dealerTotal += hiddenCard.cardWeight;
    console.log(hiddenCard)

    while (dealerTotal < 17) {
        let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
        let card = deck.pop();
        cardImg.src = "/assets/img/" + card.cardValue + "_" + card.cardSuit + ".png";
        cardImg.classList.add("card-image")
        document.getElementById("dealer-cards").append(cardImg);
        dealerTotal += card.cardWeight;
        console.log(dealerTotal);  
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
        let card = deck.pop();
        cardImg.src = "/assets/img/" + card.cardValue + "_" + card.cardSuit + ".png";
        cardImg.classList.add("card-image")
        document.getElementById("player-cards").append(cardImg);
        playerTotal += card.cardWeight;
    }  
}

function hit() {
    let card = deck.pop();
    let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
    cardImg.src = "/assets/img/" + card.cardValue + "_" + card.cardSuit + ".png";
    cardImg.classList.add("card-image")
    document.getElementById("player-cards").append(cardImg);
    playerTotal += card.cardWeight;
    checkGameOver()
}

function playAgain() {
    playerTotal = 0;
    dealerTotal = 0; 
    let cardImg = document.querySelectorAll(".card-image");
    cardImg.forEach(card => card.remove());
    startGame();
}

function checkGameOver() {
    if (playerTotal > 21) {
        console.log("Game Over");
        document.getElementById("game-over").style.visibility = "visible";
        return true;
    } else if (playerTotal <= 21) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
}

body {
    font-family:Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #006611;

}

h2 {
    padding: 20px;
}


.board-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dealer, .player {
    background: #0d7e20;
    height: 25%;
    width: auto;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5px
}

.dealer img, .player img {
    margin: 50px;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    height: 190px;
    width: 140px;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttons button {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: #b30000;
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 39px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
    background-color: #e40000;
}

#game-over {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color:  #00000070;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.game-over-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: rgb(0, 112, 37);
    height: 8vw;
    width: 18vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

#play-again {
    background-color: #b30000;
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blackjack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="board-container">
        <h2>Dealer: <span id="dealer-total"></h2>
        <div class="dealer" id="dealer-cards">
            <img id="hidden-card"src="/assets/img/cardBack_blue.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <h2>You: <span id="player-total"></h2>
        <div class="player" id="player-cards">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button onclick=hit() id="hitBtn">Hit</button>
            <button id="stayBtn">Stay</button>
        </div>       
    </div>
    <div id="game-over">
        <div class="game-over-container">
            <span>Game Over</span>
            <button id="play-again" onclick=playAgain()>Play Again</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your fix, and it works on the dealers cards, but not on the players cards. This is after I have added the classname to the players "cardImg" aswell.

Comment: My bad! I forgot to add the classname in the "hit" function aswell. It works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: It would be best if you extracted all that duplicated code into a `createCard()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's a good idea! I will try that ASAP.